# OPC-UA client SDK for C#.NET application development

Tags: c#, .net, opc, opc-ua

I have been in process of developing an application in C#.NET which can communicate to PLC through OPC server. I have searched for C#.NET based OPC 
client libraries for it and found below ones. As I have never used any of these libraries I don’t know which can be a first choice. Price do not 
matter much here. If you guys have used any of them or any other, please advise me.

http://www.opclabs.com/products/quickopc

http://advosol.com/pc-54-3-easyua-client-sdk.aspx

https://www.plccom.net/products/opc/opc-ua-toolkit.html

https://technosoftware.com/opc-ua-client-sdk-net/

https://industrial.softing.com/en/products/software/opc-development-toolkits/opc-ua-net-development-toolkit/opc-ua-net-server-client-toolkit-for-windows.html

https://www.unified-automation.com/products/client-sdk/net-ua-client-sdk.html

Comment: Nothing like warm welcome :-) I use official C# stack https://opcfoundation.org/, if money is not problem UA option (your last link) sounds good, it seems they have good customer support and in OPC-UA world (little resources) can be handy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am currently evaluating these as well.

**UPDATE**

- [Softing](https://industrial.softing.com/en/services/support/opc-toolkits.html)

  - We found another option which was Softing. Softing has an sdk which is divided into two parts. One part is a simplified version called the toolkit, and the other part is the full version called the sdk. The SDK is really just a simple wrapper around the [UA-.Net Stack](http://opcfoundation.github.io/UA-.NET/). Softing's example code was not as full featured as I would have liked. I had to flip back and forth between examples that used the SDK and examples that used the Toolkit. I was disappointed that the two were not totally compatible, and there were things we just didn't seem to be able to with the Toolkit alone. I also was disappointed that the fancy controls visible in the Softing UA Demo Client did not seem to be part of their SDK anywhere. I had to manually implement my controls, even controls as simple as a tree.

In the end, although softing worked, I would have rather spent the extra time becoming an OPC Foundation member and making use of the .Net Stack directly.

- in my research, Unified-automation has the best examples and documentation.
- Second to Unified-Automation, I liked OPC Labs. It is probably the simplest example you will find with the fewest lines of code needed, since it is component driven. OPC Labs currently is only OPC UA 1.02, so I did not go with it as I am looking for OPC UA 1.03.
- OPC Foundation probably has the most fully featured examples, but they are very complex. You have to do a lot of digging to find what you want.

  - Prevously, for OPC XI (OPC.Net) I used opc foundation's code. I was able to create a wrapper for it which was reusable, but it did take quite a bit of work.
- Technosoftware has a lot of technical issues. Missing documentation, broken links on their site, and their demo code did not compile.
- I also checked out Matrikon's Demo Kit. They are OPC UA 1.03, though they are not yet certified. Their kit is geared towards embedded devices, and is written in C. I am looking strictly at C# now, so this was not an option.
- I should also mention that Kepware has an SDK called ClientAce which supports OPC UA, but is strictly for clients.

  - I have currently only used this with OPC DA using Kepware's OPC Server.
- I did not try the remainder of the items in your list but will check them out.

Hope this helps. Let me know if you find anything significant in your research.

Comment: Brino, a big thanks for the reply with details on your evaluation of options. It helped. From my side I see the same Unified-Automation and then OPC labs as first choices form the list. Your answer accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I am in the exact same situation.  We have a .NET C# machine front end that we need to connect to a PLC that is going to be the OPC server.  I looked at all the products Brino listed. Matrikon mentioned that they will have .NET available in December. In the end I was torn between Softing and Unified Automation. Both seem like good products. But Unified Automation seems to have better examples, and documentation on the examples.

Price want not really a issue for us, we just wanted the better product. Softing wanted $3120 for 3 years support and maintenance (requirement). Unified Automation is 1900 Euros, with 1 year support and maintenance.

We will be going with Unified Automation.